# Agisoft Photoscan Normalization of Multi-Spectral Data?

Tags: agisoft-photoscan

Do you know if it is possible to normalize the data for the multi-spectral projects using a python command or a the Batch Process in Agisoft PhotoScan?

If I know the max value I can do it using something like:

```
chunk.raster_ transform.formula = ([“(B4)”] / 55000)
```

But I want the max value to be dynamic based on the

```
chunk.raster_transform.calibrateRange()
```

I am trying get something like:

```
([“(B4)”] / max)
```